# Tomcat 8.5.50 the ErrorReportValve is not working

Tags: java, tomcat8

Switching from `apache-tomcat-8.5.23` to `apache-tomcat-8.5.50`  configuring the `ErrorReportValve` is not working.
I have set below in 8.5.23 and it worked ( Tomcat does not show server info or error).

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
       showReport="false"
       showServerInfo="false"/>
```

After upgrade to `8.5.50` the tomcat shows server info and report, even I have set it to `false`

This is the sample stack trace and server info which is shown by Tomcat

[image: Tomcat error]

Any comments?

Comment: To which component (Engine, Host, Context etc.) did you add the ErrorReportValve?

Comment: Dear @MarkThomas, I have added it to Context.

Comment: I moved to `Host` and it worked thanks @MarkThomas. Please send it as answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set the configuration on the `<Host>` section in file **server.xml**.

```xml
<Host autoDeploy="false"
      appBase="webapps"
      name="localhost"
      unpackWARs="false">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
           showReport="false"
           showServerInfo="false"/>

    ...

</Host>
```

Extracted from [this Adobe ColdFusion reference](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/invalid-host-information-disclosure.html).